# Codekit Uglify.js 'Unexpected token punc' error

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, uglifyjs, codekit

**I'm not sure where my syntax / unexpected token error is**

My full jQuery function on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/gmRUa/

The error I'm getting:

```
The following error information applies to that file: 

 'Unexpected token punc, expected punc',
  line: 160,
  col: 29,
  pos: 5212,
```

[image]

Which corresponds to line 30 of [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/gmRUa/1/) the line with the `} catch {`

**Do you notice what is causing the error there?**

The function:

```
//REGISTER
var wireRegisterForm = function (form) {

console.log('inside wireRegisterForm');
var $form = $(form);

//form being submitted
$form.find('button').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    if (WORLD.validation.validateRegisterForm($form)) {

        var params = {
            "email":$form.find('#register-email').val(),
            "firstName":$form.find('#register-firstname').val(),
            "lastName":$form.find('#register-lastname').val(),
            "password":$form.find('#register-password').val()
        };

        //fill params with parameters from form
        WORLD.networking.postToServerWithAjax('/login', params, function (response) {

            //check successful or not from response object
            try {
                var isSuccessful = response.wassuccessful;
                if (isSuccessful === true) {
                    loginSuccess();
                } else {
                    // login failed
                }
            } catch {
                // login failed
            }

        });

        }

        //stop the form submit
        return false;
    });

    //enter clicked from password box
    $form.find("input[name='password']").unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.find("button").click();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was that my catch statement was wrong... this is the correct way to write a javascript catch:

```
catch(err)
```